# git log: List commits “between” two given commits

Tags: git

Consider the following git history (think of `C` as `master` and `X` a feature branch that has merged from `master` once):

```
    X
    |
    M
   /|
C E D
|/ /
B /
|/
A
```

What `git log` range revision will give me all the commits that are reachable from `X` and include the changes of `B`, i.e. `B E M X`?

NB: `git log B..X` will include `D`, which I do not want.

Comment: Commit `D` *is* reachable from `X` (via one of `M`'s parents); why do you want to exclude it from the `git log` walk? (Indeed, the only commit *not* reachable from `X` is `C`.) Note that except for the fact that branch names select particular commits, these names are essentially irrelevant: all that matters is the commit graph.

Comment: Right, that’s why `git log B..X` includes `D`, but `D` does not contain the changes from `B`, so I want to exclude it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reason to exclude `D` is that it is not a descendant of `B`,<sup>1</sup> consider using `--ancestry-path`:

```
git log --ancestry-path B..X    # or git rev-list with the same arguments
```

This does however exclude `B` in the revision walk.  To include `B` itself is slightly tricky: you have the option of `--boundary`, but that sometimes includes too many commits.  Another method is to use `B^@` to exclude all parents of `B` without excluding `B` itself.  This works whether `B` is a regular commit or a merge, and otherwise leaves the `--ancestry-path` action undisturbed.  It even works if `B` is a root commit, though in this case I am not certain that `--ancestry-path` is any use.

(If B is an ordinary single-parent commit, `git log --ancestry-path B^..X` does the trick and is simpler to think about than `B^@`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This is the reason for my comment on the original question about why you intend to exclude `D`.

Comment: Perfect! How did I miss that in `man git log`. Guess I was expecting it under “Specifying Ranges”.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log X ^A ^D
```

`^` before a ref is an exclusion.

Comment: Hmm, does't quite help, as I don't know `D` in my script

Comment: You mean before, not after.

Comment: You might then want to prefer using `--first-parent`, but your schema is a bit unclear about which parent is which.